# PDO app not retrieving records with & in TeamName

Tags: pdo

I am updating an application to use PDO, and it's fine apart from the following, I Have a database of darts League Team Names. With a prepared Select I cannot retrieve records when there is an & in the Team Name. This was not a problem with mysql and I can retrieve teams with any other character including '. How do I sanitise my select?

```
//  Get the Team Record for display.

   $stmt = $dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM Teams WHERE Season = ? AND TeamName =?');            
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $Season, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $teamname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();       
    $trow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: In answering my own question. I removed all the escape string functions from my code , but also the urlencode and urldecode from the passed parameters. It might have helped if I had checked that the Team Name was passed in it's entirety. So that 'Plough & Harrow' was not 'Plough '.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( isset ($_GET['teamName'])) {
    $teamName = ($_GET['teamName']);
    $teamname = urldecode($teamName); 
}
```

Comment: would you mind providing more context around your answer? That would help others in the future if they have the same problem.